# @graphql-codegen/typescript-react-query not generating object format for useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-codegen, tanstack

I am using @graphql-codegen/typescript-react-query to generate typescript from my graphql schema.

these are my @graphql-codegen dependencies

```
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^4.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^4.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-query": "^6.0.0",
    "@graphql-eslint/eslt-plugin": "^3.19.1",
```

my generation configuration is:

```
    "schema.ts": {
      plugins: [
        "typescript",
        "typescript-operations",
        "typescript-react-query"
      ],
      config: {
        enumValues: enumValues,
        exposeDocument: true,
        exposeQueryKeys: true,
        exposeMutationKeys: true,
        exposeFetcher: true,
        addInfiniteQuery: true
      }
    }
```

when I build the typescript from graphql the useMyQuery functions are created with property format

```
return useQuery<MyQuery, TError, TData>(
     variables === undefined ? ['myQuery'] : ['myQuery', variables],
     fetcher<myQuery, myQueryVariables>(dataSource.endpoint, dataSource.fetchParams || {}, myQueryDocument, variables),
     options
   )};
```

and not object format (as documented https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-v5)

```
 return useQuery<MyQuery, TError, TData>({
      variables === undefined ? ['myQuery'] : ['myQuery', variables],
      fetcher<myQuery, myQueryVariables>(dataSource.endpoint, dataSource.fetchParams || {}, myQueryDocument, variables),
      ...options}
    )};
```

is there a configuration item I'm missing (obviously, this code is scrubbed of identifying variable names).

thanks...

I've tried different packages and configurations

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue ```Error: Bad argument type. Starting with v5, only the "Object" form is allowed when calling query-related functions. Please use the error stack to find the culprit call. More info here: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-v5#supports-a-single-signature-one-object``` Any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `reactQueryVersion: 5` to your generation configuration.

[Source PR](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator-community/pull/434/files#diff-0e40fc3fdce3118ff7551a9e1fcd7216a6ec4951b18ea5d5f356999418e8383eR97)